# Python - converting string in text file to specific data types

Tags: python, database, type-conversion, converters

I wrote specific datatypes to an textfile (so now its all a string) as to manipulate some values of them in the textfile and afterwards read it out again as the dataypes i once wrote in.

Each row is built as an tuple (two elements), first is a string (the length can vary) and second one is a dictionary. The dictionary has one key and can vary in the amount of values. The values come up as a list of tuples (three elements) with two integers and a string in it.

Heres an example of how a row in the textfile looks like:

```
('this is a string with various lenght', {'keyasstring':[(int, int, 'string')], ... , [(...)]})
```

Also some tuples can be very long and have newlines within.

I thought i could do it with a regex. But isnt there an easier and faster way to do it?

Or maybe i could have saved or stored the data in a different way?

I am thankful for any help and hints on that matter. Thank you all in advance.

btw i am using python 3.6 on an anaconda workspace.

Comment: `pickle`, `shelve`, `json`, `csv`, anything but your homebrew format, really. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `eval()`. Example:

```
longstring = eval(('this is a string with various lenght', {'keyasstring':[(int, int, 'string')], ... , [(...)]}))
print(longstring[0])
# this is a string with various lenght
```